# Java - How to contain a switch statement menu in a while loop

Tags: java, menu, while-loop, switch-statement

I have a main menu class which gets a choice from the user and then uses that choice to select other classes from a switch statement pertaining to the menu options. My code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int dieOne = 0;
    int dieTwo = 0;
    int choice = 0;

    DiceMaker dice = new DiceMaker(); // class that creates the dice
    RollDice roll = new RollDice(); // class that imitates roll
    DiceMenu menu = new DiceMenu();
    DiceRoller series = new DiceRoller();

    System.out.println("Welcome to the Dice Roll Stats Calculator!\n");
    while (choice != 4) {
        menu.DiceMenu();
        choice = menu.getUserChoice();

        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            dice.diceMaker();
            dieOne = dice.DieOne();
            dieTwo = dice.DieTwo();
            System.out.println(dice.DieOne() + dice.DieTwo());
            return;
        case 2:
            roll.rollDice(dieOne, dieTwo);
            roll.displayRoll();
            return;
        case 3:
            series.diceRoller();
            series.displayResults();
            return;
        case 4:
            break;
        }// switch (choice)

    } // while (choice != 4)
}
```

Case for is the 'Exit' option, so I put the switch statement in a while loop with the boolean condition being not equal to 4 so that when the choice was set to 4 the loop would stop. The proper case executes but the problem I'm having is that the loop, and consequently the program stop after each case that I try, even if the choice was not 4. I tried using break statements after case 1, 2 and 3 as well, and when I did that, it would just repeat the case in an infinite loop. I tried to figure this out on my own cut could never find anything that resembled what I was seeing enough for me to figure out what the problem was. I'm guessing this probably isn't the best way to make a menu in the future. Thank in advance.

The rest of my code is as follows. Please note, DiceRoller class is still under construction, but DiceMaker and RollDice classes seem to be working.

DiceMenu class:

```
public class DiceMenu 
{
    public static final int CHOICE_UNKNOWN = 0;
    public static final int CHOICE_MAKE_DICE = 1;
    public static final int CHOICE_ROLL_ONCE = 2;
    public static final int CHOICE_SERIES_ROLL = 3;
    public static final int CHOICE_QUIT = 4;

    private int choice = 0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public int DiceMenu()
    {

        while ( this.choice < 1 || this.choice > 4 ) // while loop keeps choices in range
        {   
            System.out.println("         MAIN MENU\n");
            System.out.println("1. Create Your Dice");
            System.out.println("2. Roll Your Dice");
            System.out.println("3. Perform A Series Of Rolls And Show Stats");
            System.out.println("4. Exit\n");

            try // avoid invalid input 
            { 
                System.out.print("Please choose an option: ");
                this.choice = scan.nextInt(); // get number of sides from user
            } 
            catch (InputMismatchException e) 
            {
            //if input is invalid, returns to beginning of loop    
            System.out.println("Invalid Input. Please try again.\n");
            scan.next();
            continue;   
            }

            if ( this.choice < 1 || this.choice > 4 ) // if input is out of range
                                     // notify user before continuing
            {
                System.out.println("Choice must reflect menu options. (1-4)"
                             + " Please try again.\n");
                this.choice = 0;
            }

        }//while ( this.choice < 1 || this.choice > 4 )                 
        return 0;
    }        
    public int getUserChoice()
    {
        return this.choice;
    }       
}
```

RollDice class:

```
public class RollDice 
{
    private int roll;
    private int rollOne;
    private int rollTwo;
    private int rollTotal;

    public int rollDice (int dieOne, int dieTwo) 
    {
        this.rollOne = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * dieOne);
        this.rollTwo = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * dieTwo);
        this.rollTotal = this.rollOne + this.rollTwo;
        return 0;
    }

    public void displayRoll()
    {
        System.out.println("You roll a " + rollOne + " and a "
                       + rollTwo + " for a total of " + 
                       rollTotal + "!"); //display separate and total 
                                         //roll amounts

        if ( rollTotal == 2 ) // if/else tests for special rolls
        {
            System.out.println("Snake Eyes!");
        } 
        else if ( rollTotal == 7 )
        {
            System.out.println("Craps!");
        }
        else if ( rollOne == 6 && rollTwo == 6 )
        {
            System.out.println("Boxcars!");
        }
    }
}// public class DiceRoller
```

DiceMaker class:
    public class DiceMaker 
    {
        private int sides = 0;
        private int dieOne;
        private int dieTwo;

```
    public int diceMaker() 
    {
        while ( sides < 4 || sides > 20 ) // while loop keeps sides within        range
        {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            try // avoid invalid input 
            { 
                System.out.print("Please enter the number of sides each die "
                +            "should have (must be between 4 and 20): ");
                this.sides = scan.nextInt(); // get number of sides from user
            } 
            catch (InputMismatchException e) 
            {
            //if input is invalid, returns to beginning of loop    
            System.out.println("Invalid Input. Please try again.\n");
            scan.next();
            continue;   
            }
            if (sides < 4 || sides > 20) // if input is out of range
                                     // notify user before continuing
            {
                System.out.println("Die must have between 4 and 20 sides."
                             + " Please try again.\n");
            }
        }//while ( sides < 4 || sides > 20 )                    

        this.dieOne = sides;
        this.dieTwo = sides;
        return 0;
    }

    public int DieOne()
    {
        return this.dieOne;
    }

    public int DieTwo()
    {
        return this.dieTwo;
    }


}// public class DiceMaker
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `return`(s) from cases 1,2 and 3. If you `return` from `main` the program terminates. You want to loop so don't do that. However, as pointed out by [@ajb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2464386/ajb) in the comments below, you don't want the case(s) to fall through. So you need `break`(s).

```
case 1: dice.diceMaker();
        dieOne = dice.DieOne();
        dieTwo = dice.DieTwo();
        System.out.println(dieOne + dieTwo);
        // return;
        break; // <-- applies to innermost block (switch).
case 2: roll.rollDice(dieOne, dieTwo);
        roll.displayRoll();
        // return;
        break; // <-- applies to innermost block (switch).
case 3: series.diceRoller();
        series.displayResults();
        // return;
        break; // <-- applies to innermost block (switch).
```

Also, you could use `continue` (here, which would apply to the innermost loop). Finally, remember that case `4` terminates the loop (because `choice` is `4`) and you don't need `case 4` for that reason.

Comment: But you do need to replace the `return` with `break`, no?

Comment: add `default: break;` at the end.

Comment: @ajb Or `continue`. But yes.

Comment: @activesince93 That is not necessary. In fact, `case 4` could be eliminated entirely.

Comment: I had tried it with break statements after each case, but this leads to an infinite loop of the "display" segment of the case. For instance instead of case 1 completing and printing dice.DieOne() + dice.DieTwo(), then going back to the while loop, it just prints it infinitely. I tried it with the continue statement with the same result.

Comment: @TheStyxCrossing Post the rest of your code so we can reproduce that behavior **and/or** learn to use a debugger. Oh, and `dice.DieOne() + dice.DieTwo()` should be `System.out.println(dieOne+dieTwo);` or you call those methods **again** (which **could** be recursive, can't tell).

Comment: @Elliot Frisch Done. I will be familiarizing myself with debugging, and I apologize for not having done so already. Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: @Elliot Frisch Update: I tried debugging and stepped into case 1. When I finished that method, it printed the sum of the two die (I did change it to the "dieOne + dieTwo") and then jumps back to the beginning of the case rather than breaking. That explains the loop, but I can't understand why the break isn't exiting the switch statement altogether.

Comment: @TheStyxCrossing A switch is not a loop. Look closer.

Comment: @Elliot Frisch "A switch is not a loop." I think what you're saying is the break doesn't exit the switch statement, just goes back to the beginning of it? So what I need is to exit the switch statement and go back to the beginning of the while loop its in. I was under the impression break exited the switch statement, so how would I achieve that and call the menu method again after completing just one case?

Comment: **No**. That is the exact opposite of what I'm saying. A break ***does*** end the switch statement.

Comment: I'm really sorry if the answer is that obvious. As we speak I assure you I am going over this code again and again and googling like crazy trying to figure out what I'm missing. Isn't ending the switch statement what I want, if I want the while loop it's in to start again? Since choice != 4, wouldn't the while loop display the menu again? And why is my debugger go back to the beginning of the case 1 code after the break statement?